# PHP zona horaria

Tags: php

estoy teniendo problemas con la hora en php. Mi codigo es este:

```
date_i18n(\get_option('date', 'd/m/Y H:i:s')
```

Pero si pongo este codigo para poder canviar la hora:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
```

Tengo este error:

> Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'Europe/Madrid' is invalid

Me pueden ayudar a poner la hora de Europe/Madrid?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿estas usando wordpress?

Comment: Debería de funcionar, estoy haciendo la prueba en [PHPSandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com) y me marca la hora de Madrid las 17:09.